# Get "An unexpected error has occurred." when using MediaLibrary.GetPictureFromToken 500+ pictures on phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

i get "An unexpected error has occurred." when using MediaLibrary.GetPictureFromToken(String token). Has any one the same Problem?

Device: HTC Mozart

Comment: What are the details of the error?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this as well, and after some digging, it's because I didn't have the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB turned on in the App Caps.

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful and exciting world of "Media" programming on WP7.

You cannot access the WP7 Media library while debugging a WP7 device that is connected to Zune. The exception you described is the exception you'd normally see in this situation. You have 2 options:

1. Close Zune, and start WPConnect instead. That should allow you to debug from Visual Studio without Zune. And it even supported Media apps. the file is located on my machine @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\WPConnect\WPConnect.exe
2. Consider using the unlocked emulator ROM for debugging the Pictures hub in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your phone has run out of storage space if you've been generating a lot of data/pics/etc?

You can check this in Settings | About.